# How does IKEv2 work on Android without raw sockets

Tags: android, ipsec, ike

I was exploring the IKEv2 [StrongSwan](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan) client implementation for Android. What I fail to understand is that Android and Java do not support *raw sockets*, whilst the IKEv2/IPSec works below the transport layer, which seems counter-intuitive. How exactly does the communication happen after the `CHILD_SA` aka IPSec SA is established?

**References:**

1. The official documentation for [IKE Charon keying daemon](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon) does mention the use of 'socket' in the architecture diagram, but I was unable to find any further reference to it.
2. I'm aware of the fact that StrongSwan's Android client uses a user-space implementation of `libipsec`, but again how does `libipsec` communicate without raw sockets?

Any help to fill the gap in my understanding is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The client only supports **UDP-encapsulated ESP**. These packets are sent/received over the same UDP sockets that are already used for IKEv2. This limitation is mentioned on the [app's wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AndroidVPNClient#Known-LimitationsIssues) page.

Comment: Probably a correct answer, but would be even better with some references.

Comment: Since I'm the app's dev, I can tell you with authority it is :) But I've added a link to the wiki page where I added a note about it (basically the same information, but maybe easier to find for others).

Comment: I am a developer of the OpenConnect VPN client, which *also* supports several ESP-based VPNs, and I concur that only ESP-over-UDP is supported in Android. Basically all modern client/server VPNs use it _anyway_, since "plain" ESP-over-IP isn't reliably enough transmitted by middleboxes on the internet.

Comment: @ecdsa Thank you! That makes so much sense now. Learnt something new today :)

Comment: @ecdsa As per `libstrongswan` implementation, does that mean that we can use `DatagramSocket` or only `Charon` is allowed to keep a reference to the 'socket'. Where I'm coming from is that I need to have a split tunnel with two IKE SA, one for "work" and one for "rest of internet use".

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but there is no relation between socket and IKE or Child SA (e.g. strongSwan uses the same socket, no matter how many IKE SAs there are). But if you want to send ESP packets over a different socket, you could modify `send_esp()` in `android_service.c` (ESP packets may also be queued to _libipsec_ from other sockets).

Comment: @ecdsa Let me have a look at `send_esp()`. By two IKE SA, I meant two IKE SA with same local peer (my laptop), but different remote peers (two different VPN servers) and hence my confusion of how to use two different sockets for two IKE SA.

Comment: Again, you don't need separate sockets to have multiple IKE SAs with different servers. UDP sockets allow sending packets to arbitrary IP addresses. But note that the Android client currently only supports a single IKE and Child SA.